# Collapsible Tree example not working

Tags: r, graph, tree

I read the manual, and tried to reproduce the following example. But R produces an error:

> Error in collapsibleTree(tree, tooltip = TRUE, attribute = "Value", aggFun = identity) :  df must be a data frame

My question is what's wrong with this piece of code. I am using R version 3.4.1. Thanks!

```
# Using a flat relationship-style data frame with tooltips
Relationships <- data.frame(
    Parent = c(".",".","A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "E", "E", "F", "K", "K", "M", "M"),
    Child = c("A","K","B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "L", "M", "N", "O"),
    Value = 1:15
)

tree <- data.tree::FromDataFrameNetwork(Relationships, "Value")

# Define root node value as 0
tree$Value <- 0

# Create tree diagram with the aggregation function of identity
collapsibleTree(tree, tooltip=TRUE, attribute="Value", aggFun=identity)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added requires and ran your code, with no errors, as follows:

```
require(data.tree)
require(collapsibleTree)
Relationships <- data.frame(
  Parent=c(".",".","A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "E", "E", "F", "K", "K", "M", "M"),
  Child=c("A","K","B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "L", "M", "N", "O"),
  Value=1:15
)
tree <- data.tree::FromDataFrameNetwork(Relationships, "Value")
tree$Value <- 0
collapsibleTree(tree, tooltip=TRUE, attribute="Value", aggFun=identity)
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Is this not what you hoped for?

Comment: Interesting. The same code does not work for me. I am using " R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)" packages: data.tree       "3.4.1", collapsibleTree "3.4.1".  Is there any way to transform long format data (only contain two columns, namely, from & to) into one that collasibleTree requries?

Comment: I do not know, I used exactly your code, just added the `require()` functions at the beginning. It worked completely fine. The one thing I might check. Not all JS stuff works well in the Rstudio plot panes. Have you tried saving it as an HTML file and opening it there to see if it works in a browser window

Comment: there is error, R stops, no output at all... Any idea how to convert data by some other method? I search igraph & data.tree packages, no luck...

Comment: I am guessing that it is not that your need to change the shape as I literally cut and pasted from above and the shape was fine! It seems to be saying there is a data frame error. Run `str(Relationships)` after you set the tree value to zero...be sure that it is still a data frame. If not, convert it back with `data.frame(Relationships)` and see if that helps....

Comment: I tried str() & data.frame(), the error still exists. However, I was able to reproduce example using another win environment. Not sure why this is the case, will try to reinstall everything... thanks, anyway